# Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection with errors

Tags: help, network-configuration

I don't know what else to do, i cant get Tor to connect. This is my error log

```
2/9/2017 20:49:58 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:49:58 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:49:58 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:49:58 PM.100 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 20:49:58 PM.100 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "C:\Users\zachary.t.hibbert\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc.orig.1" 
2/9/2017 20:49:58 PM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
2/9/2017 20:49:58 PM.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
2/9/2017 20:50:57 PM.200 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host 46791D156C9B6C255C2665D4D8393EC7DBAA7798 at 31.31.78.49:443) 
2/9/2017 20:50:57 PM.200 [WARN] 10 connections have failed: 
2/9/2017 20:50:57 PM.200 [WARN]  10 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
2/9/2017 20:51:06 PM.300 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 20:51:06 PM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:51:06 PM.300 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 20:51:06 PM.300 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
2/9/2017 20:51:24 PM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:51:24 PM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:51:24 PM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:51:24 PM.000 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 20:51:31 PM.500 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 11; recommendation warn; host A832D176ECD5C7C6B58825AE22FC4C90FA249637 at 154.35.22.11:16488) 
2/9/2017 20:51:31 PM.600 [WARN] 11 connections have failed: 
2/9/2017 20:51:31 PM.600 [WARN]  11 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 12; recommendation warn; host FC259A04A328A07FED1413E9FC6526530D9FD87A at 85.17.30.79:443) 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN] 12 connections have failed: 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN]  11 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 13; recommendation warn; host 7B126FAB960E5AC6A629C729434FF84FB5074EC2 at 192.99.11.54:443) 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN] 13 connections have failed: 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN]  12 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 14; recommendation warn; host CDF2E852BF539B82BD10E27E9115A31734E378C2 at 192.95.36.142:443) 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN] 15 connections have failed: 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN]  13 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 15; recommendation warn; host A09D536DD1752D542E1FBB3C9CE4449D51298239 at 83.212.101.3:50002) 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN] 16 connections have failed: 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN]  13 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 16; recommendation warn; host C73ADBAC8ADFDBF0FC0F3F4E8091C0107D093716 at 154.35.22.9:80) 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN] 17 connections have failed: 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN]  14 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 17; recommendation warn; host BBB28DF0F201E706BE564EFE690FE9577DD8386D at 109.105.109.147:13764) 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN] 18 connections have failed: 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN]  14 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN]  3 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 18; recommendation warn; host 8DFCD8FB3285E855F5A55EDDA35696C743ABFC4E at 109.105.109.165:10527) 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN] 19 connections have failed: 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN]  14 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN]  4 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 19; recommendation warn; host 752CF7825B3B9EA6A98C83AC41F7099D67007EA5 at 198.245.60.50:443) 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN] 20 connections have failed: 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN]  15 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN]  4 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 20; recommendation warn; host FE7840FE1E21FE0A0639ED176EDA00A3ECA1E34D at 154.35.22.13:16815) 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN] 21 connections have failed: 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN]  16 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN]  4 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
2/9/2017 20:51:33 PM.400 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
2/9/2017 20:51:45 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:51:45 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:51:45 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:51:45 PM.100 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 20:51:49 PM.200 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 21; recommendation warn; host 847B1F850344D7876491A54892F904934E4EB85D at 86.59.21.38:443) 
2/9/2017 20:51:49 PM.200 [WARN] 23 connections have failed: 
2/9/2017 20:51:49 PM.200 [WARN]  17 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
2/9/2017 20:51:49 PM.200 [WARN]  4 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
2/9/2017 20:51:49 PM.200 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
2/9/2017 20:51:51 PM.600 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 20:51:51 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:51:51 PM.600 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 20:51:51 PM.600 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
2/9/2017 20:53:19 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:53:19 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:53:19 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:53:19 PM.600 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 20:53:22 PM.000 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 22; recommendation warn; host FC562097E1951DCC41B7D7F324D88157119BB56D at 128.105.214.162:8080) 
2/9/2017 20:53:22 PM.000 [WARN] 24 connections have failed: 
2/9/2017 20:53:22 PM.000 [WARN]  17 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
2/9/2017 20:53:22 PM.000 [WARN]  5 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
2/9/2017 20:53:22 PM.000 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
2/9/2017 20:53:23 PM.800 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 23; recommendation warn; host A17A40775FBD2CA1184BF80BFC330A77ECF9D0E9 at 128.105.214.163:8080) 
2/9/2017 20:53:23 PM.800 [WARN] 25 connections have failed: 
2/9/2017 20:53:23 PM.800 [WARN]  17 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
2/9/2017 20:53:23 PM.800 [WARN]  6 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
2/9/2017 20:53:23 PM.800 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
2/9/2017 20:53:23 PM.800 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 20:53:23 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:53:23 PM.800 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 20:53:23 PM.800 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 24; recommendation warn; host 1E326AAFB3FCB515015250D8FCCC8E37F91A153B at 128.105.214.161:8080) 
2/9/2017 20:53:23 PM.800 [WARN] 26 connections have failed: 
2/9/2017 20:53:23 PM.800 [WARN]  17 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
2/9/2017 20:53:23 PM.800 [WARN]  7 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
2/9/2017 20:53:23 PM.800 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
2/9/2017 20:53:23 PM.800 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 25; recommendation warn; host 0E858AC201BF0F3FA3C462F64844CBFFC7297A42 at 131.252.210.150:8080) 
2/9/2017 20:53:23 PM.800 [WARN] 27 connections have failed: 
2/9/2017 20:53:23 PM.800 [WARN]  17 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
2/9/2017 20:53:23 PM.800 [WARN]  8 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
2/9/2017 20:53:23 PM.800 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
2/9/2017 20:53:32 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:53:32 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:53:32 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:53:32 PM.600 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 20:53:39 PM.200 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 26; recommendation warn; host B9E7141C594AF25699E0079C1F0146F409495296 at 0.0.2.0:2) 
2/9/2017 20:53:39 PM.200 [WARN] 28 connections have failed: 
2/9/2017 20:53:39 PM.200 [WARN]  17 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
2/9/2017 20:53:39 PM.200 [WARN]  9 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
2/9/2017 20:53:39 PM.200 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
2/9/2017 20:53:40 PM.400 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 20:53:40 PM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:53:40 PM.500 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 20:53:46 PM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:53:46 PM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:53:46 PM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:53:46 PM.300 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 20:53:52 PM.300 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 27; recommendation warn; host A2C13B7DFCAB1CBF3A884B6EB99A98067AB6EF44 at 0.0.2.0:3) 
2/9/2017 20:53:52 PM.300 [WARN] 29 connections have failed: 
2/9/2017 20:53:52 PM.300 [WARN]  17 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
2/9/2017 20:53:52 PM.300 [WARN]  10 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
2/9/2017 20:53:52 PM.300 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
2/9/2017 20:53:53 PM.600 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 20:53:53 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:53:53 PM.600 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 20:54:00 PM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:54:00 PM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:54:00 PM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:54:00 PM.000 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 20:54:08 PM.100 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 28; recommendation warn; host AF9F66B7B04F8FF6F32D455F05135250A16543C9 at 169.229.59.75:46328) 
2/9/2017 20:54:08 PM.100 [WARN] 30 connections have failed: 
2/9/2017 20:54:08 PM.100 [WARN]  18 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
2/9/2017 20:54:08 PM.100 [WARN]  10 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
2/9/2017 20:54:08 PM.100 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
2/9/2017 20:54:09 PM.600 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 20:54:09 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:54:09 PM.600 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 20:54:09 PM.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 29; recommendation warn; host 1E05F577A0EC0213F971D81BF4D86A9E4E8229ED at 109.105.109.163:38980) 
2/9/2017 20:54:09 PM.600 [WARN] 31 connections have failed: 
2/9/2017 20:54:09 PM.600 [WARN]  19 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
2/9/2017 20:54:09 PM.600 [WARN]  10 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
2/9/2017 20:54:09 PM.600 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
2/9/2017 20:54:09 PM.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 30; recommendation warn; host A09D536DD1752D542E1FBB3C9CE4449D51298239 at 83.212.101.3:80) 
2/9/2017 20:54:09 PM.600 [WARN] 32 connections have failed: 
2/9/2017 20:54:09 PM.600 [WARN]  19 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
2/9/2017 20:54:09 PM.600 [WARN]  11 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
2/9/2017 20:54:09 PM.600 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
2/9/2017 20:54:09 PM.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 31; recommendation warn; host 4C331FA9B3D1D6D8FB0D8FBBF0C259C360D97E6A at 109.105.109.163:47779) 
2/9/2017 20:54:09 PM.600 [WARN] 33 connections have failed: 
2/9/2017 20:54:09 PM.600 [WARN]  20 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
2/9/2017 20:54:09 PM.600 [WARN]  11 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
2/9/2017 20:54:09 PM.600 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
2/9/2017 20:54:17 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:54:17 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:54:17 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:54:17 PM.600 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 20:54:26 PM.400 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
2/9/2017 20:56:00 PM.500 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 20:56:00 PM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:56:00 PM.500 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 20:56:04 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:56:04 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:56:04 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 20:56:04 PM.100 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 20:56:12 PM.400 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
2/9/2017 21:04:32 PM.600 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 21:04:32 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 21:04:32 PM.600 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 21:10:02 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 21:10:02 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 21:10:02 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 21:10:02 PM.200 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 21:10:03 PM.200 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 32; recommendation warn; host 186898801DFB07853DC73C451DD5B90E9FC4CEB4 at 162.243.94.152:8443) 
2/9/2017 21:10:03 PM.200 [WARN] 36 connections have failed: 
2/9/2017 21:10:03 PM.200 [WARN]  21 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
2/9/2017 21:10:03 PM.200 [WARN]  11 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
2/9/2017 21:10:03 PM.200 [WARN]  4 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
2/9/2017 21:13:23 PM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 21:13:23 PM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 21:13:23 PM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 21:13:23 PM.500 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 21:13:23 PM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
2/9/2017 21:13:23 PM.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
2/9/2017 21:13:44 PM.500 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (Permission denied [WSAEACCES ]; RESOURCELIMIT; count 3; recommendation warn; host A98B64A534FD145034942ADE0063A8651D47D0E6 at 37.210.57.99:443) 
2/9/2017 21:13:44 PM.500 [WARN] 2 connections have failed: 
2/9/2017 21:13:44 PM.500 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
2/9/2017 21:13:48 PM.400 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 21:13:48 PM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 21:13:48 PM.400 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 21:18:18 PM.000 [WARN] Error parsing Bridge address '06/02/2017' 
2/9/2017 21:18:18 PM.000 [WARN] Controller gave us config lines that didn't validate: Bridge line did not parse. See logs for details. 
2/9/2017 21:22:55 PM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 21:22:55 PM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 21:22:55 PM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 21:22:55 PM.300 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 21:23:00 PM.700 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 4; recommendation warn; host A2C13B7DFCAB1CBF3A884B6EB99A98067AB6EF44 at 0.0.2.0:3) 
2/9/2017 21:23:00 PM.700 [WARN] 4 connections have failed: 
2/9/2017 21:23:00 PM.700 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
2/9/2017 21:23:00 PM.700 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
2/9/2017 21:23:00 PM.700 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
2/9/2017 21:23:04 PM.900 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/9/2017 21:23:04 PM.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/9/2017 21:23:04 PM.900 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

Comment: Have you done something strange with your bridge configuration? `2/9/2017 21:18:18 PM.000 [WARN] Error parsing Bridge address '06/02/2017'`. looks weird.

Comment: You just need to add tor browser to your firewall allowed list .. it must make it work with you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a SSL MitM attack on your ISP/firewall. Try using a Meek pluggable transports.